# Connect to Mysql database from client using Mysql Connector

Tags: mysql, connection-string, mysql-connector

I want to make connection between my database on the server,that located on the internet and my application that runs on some client.
My application based on .Net framework and i using MySql Connector for .Net component.
After some searches i gain the server address for the server by execute php command below :

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

And this command returns : 67.225.166.81
I can connect to database with php when the php files runs on the server.
I used the values for connection in my .Net win app and this is the connection string :

```
string connStr = "server=67.225.166.81;port=3306;database=navayeme_joomfa;user id=navayeme;password=*****;";
```

The win app trying to make connection and an exception thrown :
Authentication to host '67.225.166.81' for user 'navayeme@myclientIP' failed ...
The myclientIP is ip of my client.
How can i fix this problem?Is possible the server doesn't support for this type of connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MySQL database together with a php script run on the same server does not mean that you can connect to the MySQL database from another network. PHP runs without a problem because it can make connection to the MySQL server on server using either

- regular TCP connection (locally)
- UNIX socket files

Please check that MySQL accepts connections on port `3306`. If firewall is used, please make sure that `3306` is allowed for incoming connection.

Comment: Looks like the user made a stealth edit to remove the PHP tag. It was *totally* there.  This question seems to actually be about the MySQL connector for .NET.

Comment: `I can connect to database with php when the *php files runs on the server.*` I get the impression that it's related with mysql not accepting connection from outside.

Comment: Thank you for writing,I only have cpanel to access the server,how i can check that MySQL accepts connections on port 3306?

Comment: It depends on your operating system. For linux/unix systems, you can use `nc` utility to connect to server on port 3306. For windows, I don't know `nc` like utility unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have access shell in the cpanel of the server,maybe i should think about using another server... however thanks for your help